# Символ "^" в OpenCL C

Tags: c, opencl

Какова роль символов `^` в этой строке?

```
void (^foo)(void) = ^{bar(...);};
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_(%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8) https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28%5Efoo%29%28void%29%3B

Comment: Исправил название темы.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В этой строке объявляется т.н. "блок". О них можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_(%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8)).

> Блоки (англ. blocks) — расширение языков программирования C, C++,
> Objective-C, не описанное в стандартах этих языков и созданное фирмой
> Apple. Расширение позволяет создавать замыкания, используя
> лямбда-подобный синтаксис.
>
> «Блоки» похожи на функции:
>
> - могут принимать аргументы и возвращать значения;
> - могут иметь локальные переменные;
> - могут вызываться, как и обычные функции;
> - имеют адреса, которые могут использоваться как обычные указатели на функцию (то есть, указатели на «блоки» могут храниться в переменных, могут передаваться в функции).
>
> В отличие от функций:
>
> - внутри «блоков» могут использоваться переменные, доступные функции, внутри которой создавался «блок».

В вашем случае объявляется блок `foo`, который ничего не принимает и ничего не возвращает. Ему присваивается блок-литерал, в котором вызывается функция `bar`.

[Пример](https://rextester.com/live/KZEN12064):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *s = calloc(100, 1);
    void (^foo)(void) = ^{ printf("Hello, %s!\n", s); };
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Мы внутри `main` определили "блок"

```
void (^foo)(void) = ^{ printf("Hello, %s!\n", s); };
```

В нём вызывается функция `printf`. Причём в самом блоке мы можем обращаться к указателю `s`, т.к. в блоке видны локальные переменные функции, в которой он создаётся.

Подробнее о "блоках" можно почитать в [документации](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html) компилятора clang.

Comment: Чем яблоку nested функции не угодили... чтоб такое изобретать :)